# npm pass command line argument to command

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, npm

I have in my npm package the following scripts property:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine-node spec/",
    "install": "browserify api-client.js -o ../www/components/global/api-client.js"
  }
```

How can I do something like

```
npm run install --param differentOutput
```

so as not to hardcode the '../www/components/global/api-client.js' path

Comment: you can create a batch file which either takes input from user or you can give him set of possible inputs to choose from

Answer (score 1):

You can use [option `--`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

```
npm run install -- --param differentOutput
```

Comment: @patentul I do not understand your additional question. Explain.

Comment: How do I modify the "install": "browserify api-client.js -o ../www/components/global/api-client.js" part afterwards?

Comment: I mean I want to have the hardcoded value if a param is not added via the CLI